# How I can provide the click on a suggestions-result (dropdown menu) in wikipedia with a selenium test in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, wikipedia

I try to write a selenium test cases in java and I am having a problem. The test involves a click on a drop down menu. But I can't reach this...

Here are my steps. First I go to the german wikipedia:

```
@Given("^You want to search for \"Baum\" on \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void youWantToSearchForOnWikipediaOrg(String page) throws Throwable
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\...\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://"+page+"/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite");
}
```

Then I search for the word "Baum":

```
@Then("^You tipp the letters \"([^\"]*)\", \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void youTippTheLettersAnd(String letter1, String letter2, String letter3) throws Throwable
{
    Thread.sleep(5);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchInput']")).sendKeys(letter1);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchInput']")).sendKeys(letter2);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchInput']")).sendKeys(letter3);
    Thread.sleep(25);
}
```

Now a dropdown menu appaers an I want to click on the entry "Baum".

```
@Then("^Click on the appearing Baum$")
public void clickOnTheAppearing() throws Throwable
{
    //Thread.sleep(50);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/div")).click();
}
```

But xpath can't find the element.
I try different xpath and css, but nothing helps...

Examples:

```
//*[@classname='mw-searchSuggest-linkinput']//*[text()='Baum']

/html/body/div[6]/div/a[1]/div/span

/html/body/div[6]/div/a[1]/div

body > div.suggestions > div > a:nth-child(1) > div > span
```

The website:
[image]

Comment: is dropdowns in side iframe?

Comment: No.
It appears when u insert the letter of the search item below to it.

Comment: i mean to say when you inspect those, are they inside <iframe> tag?

Comment: No. I add a picture from the "website"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put some wait and after that element load use the following:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@title='Baum']")).click();
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of click, Select the value from drop down.

`Webelement e1=driver.findElement(By.id(dropdownId));
   Select s1=new Select(e1);
   s1.selectByVisibleText("Baum");//selecting value from dropdown`